# request for member 'title' not a structure or union?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

```
    #import "RootViewController.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @implementation RootViewController


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath {
    // UITableViewStyleGrouped table view style will cause the table have a textured background
    // and each section will be separated from the other ones.
    DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc]
                                        initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped
                                        andfileData:[dao   libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    controller.title = [[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Description"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

compile with error..had imported all the files..wat went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I'm guessing that the controller object (of class DetailViewController) doesn't actually have the property "title" as is needed for the "dot-syntax" to work.

Does DetailViewController properly inherit from UIViewController?

Comment: Carson: Yea, make sure that DetailViewController is inheriting from UIViewController (NOT UIView). That error generally means that there's no property with the given name and you didn't include the interface definition for DetailViewController, so we have no way of knowing what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Is the controller being init'd properly? Did you check if its null or something's wrong?
Put a breakpoint on it and check it out:

```
 DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
[controller setTitle:[[dao libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Description"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
self->Title //... Your code here
```

Or try with a method like this:

```
 -(void)setTitle: (NSString*)aTitle;
{
    [self->Title setString:aTitle];
}
```